SQL Server two tables
I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'm trying to find the best workaround.
I have two tables:
Table1:



A
B
C




aa
bb
js[12]


cc
dd
js[45]



Table2:



A
B
C
D




aa
bb
js[1]
js[2]


cc
dd
js[4]
js[5]



Column "A" in table 1 is AUTO_INCREMENTED, for id generation. An app sends the JSON into column C. I want to parse Json from that column, and insert those parts into table 2.
I figured out how to parse JSON and insert it, but I can't find the best solution to copy the data properly, because a WHERE condition is expected to be fulfilled during data transition. I can't find a solution how to create reference between those two tables.
My current code is:
INSERT INTO operation (ref)
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(info, '$.ReferenceID')

INSERT INTO operation (isdp)
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(info, '$.isDenominatePossible')

INSERT INTO operation (crid)
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(info, '$.current_rate.ID')

INSERT INTO operation (fcc)
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(info, '$.current_rate.Currency')

And this is the result I get:



ref
isdp
crid
fcc




00716631
NULL
NULL
NULL


00716632
NULL
NULL
NULL


00716633
NULL
NULL
NULL


00716634
NULL
NULL
NULL


00716635
NULL
NULL
NULL


00716636
NULL
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
true
NULL
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
1
NULL


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD


NULL
NULL
NULL
USD



Is it possible to arrange those values in one row?
I want to get this instead:



ref
isdp
crid
fcc




00716631
true
1
USD


00716632
true
1
USD


00716633
true
1
USD


00716634
true
1
USD


00716635
true
1
USD


00716636
true
1
USD




If you want to replicate data inserted into one table,by inserting all or parts into another table, you can create a trigger that will do it on insert

@T.S. Thank you for your reply.
I don`t need to use triger yet. i still trying to do it manually, because there is issues with replicating the data properly

@jarlh incorrect syntax

Read up on OPENJSON, there's no need to use JSON_VALUE here me thinks. The main problem is that your explanation is very vague, you should probably just post the json and the expected result

Hard to be sure without better samples, but try this:
INSERT INTO operation (ref, isdp, crid, fcc)
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.ReferenceID'),
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.isDenominatePossible'),
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.current_rate.ID'),
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.current_rate.Currency')
FROM ...

